# Changing arguments in Function after Importing

Tags: python, function

I have a script which has a function that is used in various classes and other functions throughout the script.

For example:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(i):
   x = beta.pdf(i,a=10,b=2, scale = 100, loc = -50)
   return x

def plotme():
    graphme = []
    for i in range(500):
        graphme.append(function(i))
    plt.plot(graphme)

def average():
    averageme = []
    for i in range(500):
        averageme.append(function(i))
    average = sum(averageme)/float(len(averageme))
    return print(average)
```

Now if I wanted to import the module and call plotme() or average() it would use the values that are in the function(i). But is there a way for me to change the values of a, b, scale, and loc in function(i) when importing it?  I know I could change each function to allow for it to change but I am hoping I could just adjust the initial function.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.function(i, a = 500, b = 200, scale = 50, loc = 0)
mymodule.plotme()
```

And the plotme() would be based on the new values not what is coded in the script.

Comment: Ideally, `plotme()` and `averageme()` would take a function as one of their parameters, so you can apply them to whatever function you want.

Comment: Can't you just pass a, b, scale and loc as arguments and assign default values for them? `def function(i, a=10, b=2, scale=100, loc=-50)`, you can have the default values as constants in your module and pass them to the other functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching your module, you could monkey-patch it after importing it.  One way, using your example:

```
import mymodule

def function(i):
   x = beta.pdf(i, a=500, b=200, scale=50, loc=0)
   return x

mymodule.function = function
mymodule.plotme()
```

I agree with commenter jasonharper that mymodule's functions could have a better API.

Comment: I agree it could be better! I am just looking for a quick and dirty solution and this works well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you can change existing implementation, it should have a class which makes it possible to modify these parameters:

```
class WhateverYouCallIt:
    def __init__(a=10, b=2, scale=100, loc=-50):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 2
        self.scale = scale
        self.loc = loc

    def function(self, i):
        return beta.pdf(i, a=self.a, b=self.b, scale=self.scale, loc=self.loc)

    def plotme(self):
        graphme = []
        for i in range(500):
            graphme.append(self.function(i))
        plt.plot(graphme)

    def average(self):
        averageme = []
        for i in range(500):
            averageme.append(self.function(i))
        average = sum(averageme)/float(len(averageme))
        return print(average)
```

Then you can have several differently parameterized instances:

```
default_one = WhateverYouCallIt() # the default
default_one.plotme()
default_one.average()

a_different_one = WhateverYouCallIt(a=500, b=200, scale=50, loc=0)
a_different_one.plotme()
a_different_one.average()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
import mymodule

# and any time you need you assign a partial func to your function
mymodule.function = partial(mymodule.function(a=500, b=200, scale=50, loc=0))
...
mymodule.function(i)
...
```